# What is the factor equal to if the true and empirical distribution both are 0 for a configuration?

Tags: mathematical-statistics, distance, kullback-leibler

Suppose I want to calculate the relative entropy:

$$D(q||p)= \sum q(x)\log \frac{q(x)}{p(x)}$$

If, for some $x$, I have $q(x)=p(x)=0$, does the corresponding factor in the sum becomes $0$?

Comment: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference Please use math typesetting.

Comment: If $q(x)=0$, why would you even include that term in the sum?  By definition, it has no chance of occurring.

Comment: That's true, but I'm actually computing the KL distance of a Bayesian network, and I need to include such parameters in the code for the package to work.

Comment: Yes, but doesn't that consideration alone immediately tell you what the only possible correct answer can be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kullback%E2%80%93Leibler_divergence) has the answer. Yes, the corresponding term becomes $0$.

In more detail (from wiki): For discrete distributions,

> The Kullback–Leibler divergence is defined only if $q(x)=0$ implies
>   $p(x)=0$, for all $x$ (absolute continuity). Whenever $p(x)$ is zero the
>   contribution of the x-th term is interpreted as zero because
>   $\lim _{x\to 0}x\log(x)=0$

That is if both probabilities are $0$ you take the limit which, is $0$ for that term of the sum.